# Ohm as unit for numeric formating in objects

Tags: palantir-foundry

I want to crate an object in the ontology which contains different measurements.

For the resistance measurements I need the unit Ohm, kOhm and MOhm in the numeric formatting.

In the standard units list I can`t find them. Is it possible to add them?

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's in the list, can you take the path of least resistance and do a workaround for now? I'll pass this question as feedback internally.

Comment: "path of least resistance" 

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "Standard Unit" once you've toggled Numeric, try the "Custom" option. There you can add the unit for *Ohm* to fit your use case.

And of course depending on the data this could be anything custom like *Packs* or *Requests* or *Pipettes*...